# Is it possible to start firefox with homepage in a pinned tab?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I set Firefox (7) to start up with a few homepages automatically. Problem is that it only opens in 'normal tabs', but I want to keep them nicely pinned so they don't take too much space.

I'm clearing my browsing history on every exit, so I can't just let FF reopen all the tabs that were opened before, not to mention that I only want my homepages to open on a FF startup, and not all the rest.

Anyone knows whether it's possible to open the homepage automatically in a pinned tab in Firefox ? Would be a cool feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have FF.7 to test it on but it looks like ....
You can pin a webpage with right click on tab and 'pin as app' but this seems to require
 the remembering of history, cookies, etc.
So you can do it but you have to save information that FF.7 would use to open pinned pages.
I also could not find an add-on that would do this, alot of bookmark pins but none as you have asked for.
 It's possible the ['dev hub'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/)  maybe looking to do something, but that would be up to you.
I could have [missed something](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?sid=c8c85bfb37e59e6e0aba17bdeb8306de%22%20%22)
This may help you have a [smaller start load](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/home-double-click-extens-14246/?src=search),
 but is not answer you are after.
Sorry i could not help.

Comment: actually you did help me. I didn't know that pinned tabs get restored nonetheless whether you set ff to open with the old tabs or not as long as you don't delete the browsing history. although it's not 100% what I want (I actually want to delete browsing history), it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The Session Manager add-on allows you to set a saved session as the default startup session for Firefox. So, a way to achieve what you want, AND be able to delete your browsing history without messing up starting with the pinned tab would be:

1. Install Session Manager add-on, restart
2. With only one tab (& window) open, navigate to the site you wish to be your pinned site.
3. Pin the tab as an app tab
4. Use session manager to save the session. I call mine 'default'.
5. Under Session Manager Options

   - Startup & Shutdown
   - set the "At startup always load the following session" option to 'select session'
   - choose the default session you just saved.

Firefox will now start with whatever tabs you had in that session (which I guess will just be your pinned tab), every time.